# How do I determine an image's color space in Java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, colors, color-space

I am trying to determine an image's color space in Java. I believe this is referred to as "imageType" in the BufferedImage class. This is the line of code which causes me trouble - I don't know what to put as the third argument:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

I'm going to stitch several images together into the BufferedImage using the class Graphics2D. Some images I use may be in RGB format, others in ARGB, 4-byte ARGB etc...

Is there any way I can programatically determine the color spaces of the images? Or if not, is there a way of converting all images into the same color space before stitching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ColorConvertOp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html) class can be used to convert an image from one ColorSpace to another.

[`BufferedImage.getType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getType%28%29) can be used to determine the color space used by the image.